# Keeping one variable constant in a parametric surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Let us consider the parametric surface $F(u,v)$, now say we consider the curve $F(u,v_0)$. In my book, they always show this curve as a curve that is projected on the say, $xy$ plane creates a straight line. This is not always the case, right? It is a line in the "domain" of $F(u,v)$ but depending on the parametrization, it could be a very crazy squiggly line that in no way resembles a line no matter how we project it onto whichever plane. If what I am saying is true, then given a point and taking the partial derivatives of the parametric equation, there is no guarantee that these tangent vectors will be perpendicular at all. Yet, my book shows, in all the diagrams, that that is the case. Is it just an unfortunate illustration problem, or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of $F$ is it ?, what is the relation between $u,v$ and $x,y$ ? etc. ?

Comment: $F(u,v)=f(u,v)i+g(u,v)j+h(u,v)k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. The partial velocities $F_u$ and $F_v$ (where $F = (x,y,z)$ parametrizes a surface) need not be perpendicular. That special condition $F_u \cdot F_v =0$ makes the parametrization nice and often we form $F$ by freezing on of a triple of an orthonormal coordinate system so the $F$ has this property. For example,
$$ F(\phi, \theta) = (R\cos \theta \sin \phi, R\sin \theta \sin \phi, R \cos \phi) $$
for sphere of radius $R$ freezes $\rho = R$, or
$$ F(\theta, \rho) = (\rho\cos \theta \sin \phi_o, \rho\sin \theta \sin \phi_o, \rho\cos \phi_o) $$
parametrizes the cone $\phi = \phi_o$. We can construct half-planes parametrized by $\rho, \phi$ by freezing $\theta = \theta_o$ in the same fashion. Then cylindrical coordinates allow easy parametrizations of cylinders in much the same fashion. All of this said, it's easy to give $F$ which are not like this:
$$ F(u,v) = (u+v,u,u+v) $$
has $F_u = (1,1,1)$ and $F_v=(1,0,1)$ and $F_u \cdot F_v \neq 0$ is a parametrization of a plane with tangent vectors $\langle 1,1,1 \rangle$ and $\langle 1,0,1 \rangle$. Since $\langle 1,0,-1 \rangle$ is perpendicular to both tangent vectors we discern it is normal to the plane $x=z$ (in retrospect, seeing this is the Cartesian equation of the plane is fairly obvious).

Comment: Dr. Cook, I wouldn’t say it’s fairly obvious. It sure wasn’t last semester. 

Comment: @Prime $x=u+v=z$ so $x=z$ so $x-z=0$. On the other hand $y=u$ so $y$ is free. A calculus III student would probably calculate $F_u \times F_v$ rather than just guessing a perpendicular as I did here...

Comment: I mean. Probably. Not gonna lie, going into your office hours seems intimidating. I haven’t been yet, but perhaps I will next semester.

Comment: haha will do! And any chance you’ll move upstairs considering one office should be....erm...vacant...considering recent events?

Comment: ah. You don’t like the little 1980’s cubicles? Darn. Anyway...any idea who I am yet?

Comment: 1. I take it you *might* have seen a question I posted about “large” functions?

Comment: I had not seen that question, there are many things I do not see... that said, that had many interesting answers. I think the context of that comment was a bit hard to make precise for a post here. My imagination for largest function was implicitly limited to typical series formulas given in Calculus II. Naturally, if we forget textbook questions and pursue faster growing things then there are endless games to play as you saw in the responses of the MSE.

Comment: the question was posted with genuine curiosity. I promise. Perhaps I could email you with a question about how to rigorously define a “parent function”?

Comment: The "parent functions" are some standard list of given functions. Then sums, products, differences, composites etc. are used to construct new functions. The choice of "parents" is mostly just an adhoc choice of precalculus texts. I have not too much to say more than that. There are deeper things known about elementary functions... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm but I do not know these things deeply.

Comment: hmm will do. I’ll make sure to stop by your office hours this next semester!